# How can I use zIndex in 0.23

Tags: react-native

I know zIndex was added in react-native@0.30, but our project is still @0.23 due to the difficult upgrading. But I still want to use zIndex so that the background view can be clicked. Can anyone help me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click through certain element to background, you could use `pointerEvents={'none'}`. This can be conditional based on your needs whether the background is clickable in that case.

But to be honest, I don't understand how zIndex would solve your case, if you have *"clickable background"* and then *"element foreground"*. Could you post some code if this answer didn't solve your case?

Comment: I was using ListContainer from facebook f8 , but I find the parallaxBackground can not be clicked because the listView is located above the parallaxBackground. So I try in react-native@0.39 with the zIndex and it can be clicked.

Comment: I have tryed, pointerEvents='none' does make the listview unclickable, but the prarallaxBackgroud still can not get the touch event.